# What should my directory be in this code?

Tags: python, path, google-colaboratory

https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/predicting-car-price-from-scraped-data/tree/master/picture-scraper

I'm attempting to run the main.py file on google colab but get an error due to the directory I have put. I have put the path as the folder containing the .py files. I have put the directory as the folder containing the images but I recieve this error.

```
python3: can't open file '/content/gdrive/My': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

code:

```
import os

path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper' #Where the .py files are located

os.chdir(path)

directory = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset' #Where the images are located

files = ['scrape', 'tag', 'save', 'select']

if __name__ == '__main__':
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)

[os.system('python ' + path + f'{file}.py ' + directory) for file in files]
```

Comment: try using `path = r"/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper"` and `directory = r"/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset"`

Comment: Same error as before

Comment: if you read the error (`can't open file '/content/gdrive/My'`) it only complains about part of the path, so I guess, it cannot read the complete path, because of the space.

Comment: try `'"/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper"'` (notice the double quote)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this as your loop:

```
[os.system('python ' + path + f'{file}.py ' + directory) for file in files]
```

Use this instead:

```
for file in files:
    command = f'python {path}{file}.py {directory}'
    print('Running command:', command)  # for debugging purposes
    os.system(command)
```

When you do, I suspect that you'll see this output:

```
Running command: python /content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraperscrape.py /content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset
Running command: python /content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scrapertag.py /content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset
Running command: python /content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scrapersave.py /content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset
Running command: python /content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraperselect.py /content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset
```

And I suspect that if you copy and paste those commands into a command line, none of the commands will work.  In fact, you'll likely get the error you were seeing earlier, which was:

```
python3: can't open file '/content/gdrive/My': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

To make them work, change this line:

```
command = f'python {path}{file}.py {directory}'
```

to:

```
command = f'python "{path}/{file}.py" "{directory}"'
```

Then you'll see this output:

```
Running command: python "/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper/scrape.py" "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset"
Running command: python "/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper/tag.py" "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset"
Running command: python "/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper/save.py" "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset"
Running command: python "/content/gdrive/My Drive/picture-scraper/select.py" "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Car Dataset"
```

And now, if you copy and paste those commands into your terminal, they should work.  (In fact, the commands should already be running, so you don't even have to copy-and-paste them to test them.)

(I confess, I have not tested this output.)

If it does work, you can remove the debug line.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks' J-L it runs the main.py file. There seems to be a problem with exporting the .csv files from scraper.py and also from tag.py any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @MTas:  If the scraper.py and tag.py programs have trouble exporting the .csv files, it seems like it's a problem with them, and not with the main file (which I assume is the file you posted here).  Without looking at them, there's no way I can tell you what's wrong with them.  (You can make sure they work individually, and then they should work from the main file.)